# Text is not updating on button in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-compose-button

I want to change the text that's appearing on the button each time I click it, so I have written the following code, but it's not working. Where am I going wrong?

```
    class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            var i=0;
            Button(onClick = {i++ }) {
                Text("Clicked $i times") //!!not updating here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check how compose works with [states and recomposition](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-and-composition).

Use something like:

```
var i by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

Button(onClick = {i++ }) {
    Text("Clicked $i times")
}
```